# How to set chrome binary path for webbot?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run the following code on Windows 7 and pycharm IDE

```
from webbot import Browser
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com')
```

and I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Samhitha/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/web_bot.py", line 10, in 
> web = Browser()
> File "C:\Users\Samhitha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\webbot\webbot.py", line 68, in **init**
> self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, options=options)
> File "C:\Users\Samhitha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in **init**
> desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
> File "C:\Users\Samhitha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
> self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
> File "C:\Users\Samhitha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
> response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
> File "C:\Users\Samhitha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)
> File "C:\Users\Samhitha\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Could someone shed light on how I could resolve this? (I tried setting up binary location as well as chrome driver location through selenium webdriver but that didn't help either)